# get current page in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

For instance if I have http://www.mywebsite.com/about.aspx. Store about.aspx (or whatever page we're on) in a variable. Also need this to work even if there is information after the page in the url such as a query string.

Comment: I decided to just go with if (Request.Path.Contains("Dashboard.aspx"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah - I suggest you read [the ASP.NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) VERY carefully. The HttpRequest object, available as Request property contains all information that you can have about the request. This includes the path called, all parameters etc.

Comment: I'm familiar with the Request property and how you can retrieve the url path, but I wasn't sure if there was a property to simply get the current page name or if I had to do a request.path and parse it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Weighing in a little late, but others may get here as I did.

You could try to use a combination of the Uri and Path objects. For example:

```
Uri test = new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com/default.aspx?id=7&em=958");            
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(test.AbsolutePath));
```

Not sure if this is the "proper" way but it works for me.